# LibHaru for iOS adding custom annotation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf, libharu

I am interested in Creating PDF in one of my iPad apps. The issue is that i need an Image as a annotation. So when some when clicks on that image the annotation message pops up. I learned that using libHaru one can add annotations in PDF which I got working but the Image for annotations are predefined in libHaru. Can anyone suggest me how to add my custom image to the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial should help: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1 (part 2 adds an image.) If you need more than 1 image, go to the forum and he adds a suggestion for multiple images.

Comment: thanks for the response Beth but I need to actually add an Image as annotation. Which CGPDF doesnt support. libHaru does this thing but it comes with its own built in Annotation Images. It is in C and really hard to find how I can place my custom image instead of that.